# cant get audacity installed via terminal

Tags: dependencies

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

If I install audacity by snap store everything works except It won't play sound - which is kinda a deal breaker. I know it works if I install it by terminal and not snap.

Recently I deleted a PPA for makehuman and it also deleted some other packages (yes, I'm an idiot), now when I try to install audacity by terminal I get this message.

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies.
 audacity : Depends: libflac++10 (>= 1.4.1~) but it is not installable
            Depends: libflac12 (>= 1.3.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libportsmf0 but it is not installable
            Depends: libsbsms10 (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libwxbase3.2-1 (>= 3.2.2+dfsg) but it is not installable
            Depends: libwxgtk3.2-1 (>= 3.2.1+dfsg-2) but it is not installable
            Depends: libavcodec60 (>= 10:6.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libavformat60 (>= 10:6.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've been searching for hours how to fix this, everything is upgraded, how do I fix this please?

results from policy :

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntuhandbook1-audacity,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Audacity Audio Editor and Recorder,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpadcontent.net
 500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntuhandbook1-audacity,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Audacity Audio Editor and Recorder,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpadcontent.net
 500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tatokis/ckb-next/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-tatokis-ckb-next,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=ckb-next,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpadcontent.net
 500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main all Packages
     release o=microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy,c=main,b=all
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main armhf Packages
     release o=microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy,c=main,b=armhf
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main arm64 Packages
     release o=microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy,c=main,b=arm64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 Packages
     release o=microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-graphics-drivers,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Proprietary GPU Drivers,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpadcontent.net
 500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-graphics-drivers,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Proprietary GPU Drivers,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpadcontent.net
 500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable amd64 Packages
     release o=Docker,a=jammy,l=Docker CE,c=stable,b=amd64
     origin download.docker.com
 500 http://www.deb-multimedia.org stable/main i386 Packages
     release v=12.5,o=Unofficial Multimedia Packages,a=stable,n=bookworm,l=Unofficial Multimedia Packages,c=main,b=i386
     origin www.deb-multimedia.org
 500 http://www.deb-multimedia.org stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12.5,o=Unofficial Multimedia Packages,a=stable,n=bookworm,l=Unofficial Multimedia Packages,c=main,b=amd64
     origin www.deb-multimedia.org
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 100 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: If you were using 22.04 LTS or *jammy*, the default package requirements are show at https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/audacity so either you're not using the Ubuntu package(s) OR have polluted your system rather extensively. Have you explored what you're installing (`apt policy audacity` etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: I installed it a week ago, and it got deleted when I deleted the ppa for makehuman - so I'm guessing I messed up something bad. I see a list after the policy command but im a linux noob so im not sure where to go - I installed audacity before by "sudo apt-get insall audacity" and it worked then

Comment: @guiverc I tried all that before I came here

Comment: We're limited to knowing details you provide in your actual question, ie. for us to see results from `apt-cache policy` you'd need to provide the command & output in your actual question... that would be useful detail.  Please provide additional details via edits to your question (*this is a Q&A site and not a forum*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Remove packages sources that are pointing to Debian. Acka deb-multimedia.